# in Python trying to use cv2.matchShapes() from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have done a random drawing on a whiteboard and NAO robot has taken a picture and tried to re-create the same drawing.

My drawing:

[image]

NAO's drawing:

[image]

At this point I would like to write some conclusions about it, specifically I want to extract the contours from both pictures and match the contours using the `OpenCV` function `cv2.matchShapes()`.

However, I wrote a small `Python` code script for this and it gives me some errors. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#get the pictures from the forlder
original = cv2.imread('eightgon.jpg')
drawn = cv2.imread('eightgon1.jpg')

#make them gray    
originalGray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
drawnGray = cv2.cvtColor(drawn, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#apply erosion
kernel = np.ones((2, 2),np.uint8)
originalErosion = cv2.erode(originalGray, kernel, iterations = 1)
drawnErosion = cv2.erode(drawnGray, kernel, iterations = 1)

#retrieve edges with Canny
thresh = 175
originalEdges = cv2.Canny(originalErosion, thresh, thresh*2)
drawnEdges = cv2.Canny(drawnErosion, thresh, thresh*2)

#extract contours
originalContours, Orighierarchy = cv2.findContours(originalEdges, cv2.cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
drawnContours, Drawnhierarchy = cv2.findContours(drawnEdges, cv2.cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print cv2.matchShapes(drawnContours,originalContours,cv2.cv.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
```

When I run this simple code, it returns me this error:

```
File "C:/Python27/getResults.py", line 32, in <module>
    ret = cv2.matchShapes(drawnContours,originalContours,cv2.cv.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
TypeError: contour1 is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Since the error tells me that the contours should be arrays.. I make a slight change in the code like this:

```
cnt1 = np.asarray(drawnContours, np.int0)
cnt2 = np.asarray(originalContours, np.int0)
print cv2.matchShapes(cnt1,cnt2,cv2.cv.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
```

and in this case it returns me this error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is apreciated!

Comment: btw, you're trying to *use* matchShapes(), not *implement* it. (that's already done).

Comment: ok, sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem. The match shapes function takes a single contour pair, not the whole contour container pair.

```
cv2.matchShapes(drawnContours[i], originalContours[i], cv2.cv.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The documentation claims matchShapes also takes a pair of images. How would you combine the information from an arbitrary number of contours?

Comment: @jtlz2 - Pair of images would work, but not arrays of images/contours.

Answer (score 2):

Here the `drawnContours` and `originalContours` are a list of contours contained in the image.
Use `drawnContours[i]` and `originalContours[i]` so that it represent a specific contour, where i = 0,1,2...n-1, and n is the total number of contours in the image.

For example,

```
print cv2.matchShapes(
    drawnContours[0], originalContours[0], 
    cv2.cv.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
```

To get the total number of contours in a image, use:

```
n = len(drawnContours)  # n is the number of contours
print n
```

Answer (score -3):

Check the opencv version, older release should have different matchShapes or findContours API.

Because sadly some NAO software release enclosed some rather old opencv version.

Think about updating your NAO Software, or try to get some beta one...

Comment: There was actually a problem in the `matchShapes` call, he provided the total list of contours.